# query string based behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages: Default.aspx and Target.aspx. On Default.aspx are two buttons: 
Button1 redirects to `("~/Target.aspx?mode=\"drop\"");` 
Button2 redirects to `("~/Target.aspx?mode=\"textbox\"");`

On Target.aspx is following behind code:

```
string display = Request.QueryString["mode"];
    switch (display)
    {
        case "textbox":
            TextBox1.Visible = true;
            DropDownList1.Visible = false;
            break;
        case "drop":
            TextBox1.Visible = false;
            DropDownList1.Visible = true;
            break;

    }
```

As you can see, in case of Button1, Target.aspx should hide TextBox1 and display DropDownList1. However this doesn't work. Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make redirect to  ("~/Target.aspx?mode=drop");
**drop / textbox without quotes in redirect URL**

Comment: @polohy nice to hear it solved you problem :) Don't forget to mark an answer, thx :)

Comment: maybe one more issue. This works with button, but not with asp:hyperlink. Do you know why ?

Comment: Check what is the output of hyperlink on client (HTML)...hyperlink redirects to URL without submiting, so it's required to see the output on client.